# When I use facebook connect how much access do I have to the user's friends?

Tags: php, facebook

So, if you sign in using facebook on my website, how much access do I have to your friends? I am asking this question because I want for example to know if a user asks me a question about his/her friend, I can go through their Facebook status messages for example and tell them the answer depending on parsing information but do I have access to the user's friends information or no? (And how can I do that if it is possible in another way)

Comment: Unless the friend has opted-in, I would hope you would have ZERO access.

Comment: @Frustrated, bizarrely (or evilly, if you prefer), Facebook now considers a user's entire friends list "Publicly available information" (http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=16374)

Comment: Well the friends' list includes only the names of your friends but does that include any other information about them or is it only their names?

Comment: @Matthew: So how is this information accessed? I have always had my privacy settings set to "Only Friends" or "Only Me". Would I only appear as a friend in in my friend's publicly available list? If everyone of my friends tightened up their privacy settings, would the info no longer be "publicly available"?

Comment: @Frustrated, I checked, and if Bob authorizes, the app can see most of the publicly available info for all of Bob's friends (incl. say his friend Rich's id, first and last name, profile URI).  But it doesn't look like it can access a full list of Rich's friends.  So if neither you nor your friends ever authorize the API, then apps can't access you this way (for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the Facebook API has recently changed (it's now the "[Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api)").  As of now, you go to http://graph.facebook.com/username/friends after authenticating with OAuth.  As always, there will be copious libraries to help.